# Просмотр и редактирование формул

Tags: java, android

Нужно иметь возможность отображать и редактировать формулу с косинусами, корнями, логарифмами. Это нужно свою `custom view` создавать или может быть есть что-то готовое? Например такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы был курсор и его можно было перемещать по формуле.

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение для отображения формул https://www.mathjax.org/

Документация https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Guide:-MathJax-in-Android-apps

Пример приложения https://github.com/leathrum/android-apps

Comment: На сколько я вижу, она дает возможность только отображать формулу, но не редактировать её как EditText